# Monitoring copied file to a USB key

Tags: usb

I'm using USBguard to prevent users from connecting an untrusted device to their machines (Unix).

Once the device is trust, I would like to keep logs of which file is copied to a USB key. I would like to have :

```
the username
the timestamp
the file name
and the most important for me : the hash of the file
```

Which tool can I use to do so ?

Thanks